# deleting a user unlocked all locked files by that user in perforce

Tags: linux, admin, perforce, root

I've deleted a particular user from perforce which has removed the locks from the files where that user has placed a lock.

I'd expect the lock to remain, so why is it not happening ? What should be done to do so ?
I've removed his workspaces as part of the procedure to remove the perforce user.

Comment: Not actually familiar with Perforce, but who would you expect to hold the locks after the user is deleted? Locks in RCS are used to avoid commit conflicts between multiple users, once the user is deleted there should not be any more commits from that user. Are you trying to use locks as an access restriction mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean someone ran the `p4 lock` command?  Or perhaps the files are set for exclusive checkout?

In either case, once the user is gone those locks have no meaning, as they are tied to a user and workspace.  If you want to restrict edits on those files, you can lock them again or change the protections on the files.

Comment: Yes I meant the 'p4 lock' locked files. Thanks ( I locked them again. ). I realize that when the user is no more the lock will also go. Got confused from a web page which said nonexisting user's lock - but not the deleted user...